# How can I interpret very high values of lambda in a BoxCox transformation?

Tags: python, data-transformation

I got a skewed datset. (I also tested it with the python method .skew() and the value was 398) So I wanted that my datset is not that skewed anymore and found the method BoxCox. I then implemented this in Python and got a lambda value of -21.57. On the internet I found out that you can only use the BoxCox transformation if the lambda value is between -5 and 5. What can I do now? How can I interpret the value of -21.57? And why does the BoxCox transformation not work?

Comment: BoxCox does not work if 1) there are outliers, 2) your data can not be transformed with the power transformation -> something similar to Normal distribution. It would be useful for us to see the plots before / after the transformation to say something meaningful.

Comment: @GermanDemidov Outliers are sometimes in the eye of the beholder. I would say that the most common single application of Box-Cox is to suggest a power or logarithm transformation and apparent outliers are often tamed by such a transformation. It might be better to say, with some risk of circularity, that genuine outliers are those that can't be tamed by some standard transformation.

Comment: I didn't plot the after the transformation, because the lambda value is so high and I thought it didn't make any sense then. Should I do it anyway?

Comment: A skew of 398 is consistent with many configurations. What's important going forward is to know much more about your data.

Comment: Showing us say the 5 smallest and the 5 largest values is often helpful.

Comment: 5 largest values: 251, 178, 174, 170, 165
5 smallest values: 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
(this are the original data. I shifted every value with plus one, because of the boxcox only works with positive values)

Comment: oh I guess it is zero inflated distribution which, of course, can not be transformed to normal.

Comment: Are these discrete (e.g. counts) and is the most common value zero? If so, you haven't got a hope of getting a normal distribution out of this as the mode will remain the mode whatever you do. But that doesn't rule modelling with a logarithmic link or something like a root transformation being of some help.

Comment: Yes, I look for counts and the most common value ist zero, so that I got a very right skewed datset. 
But how cold I avoid the skew, if the BoxCox is not the right method for me?

Comment: Skewness is a fact for your data, not a problem to be avoided.  You haven't said what your goal is, so specific advice is difficult, beyond that already given in my previous comment (for "rule" there read "rule out").

Comment: I want to cluster my data. That's why I want to transform the different features beforehand. For some features the lambda value was good, but for some just not. I want to see what influence different transformations have on my cluster formation. Do you have any idea what else I could try?

Comment: I've already suggested the root. Another possibility is the cube root. You already know about log(count + 1).  I can't see that transformation is required before clustering, unless it's some kind of standardization.